# Shell script crashes and does not print to file?

Tags: java, shell, kotlin, ktor

I am managing a VPS in which I want to keep running a JAR file which is acting as a secure websocket server.
I am noticing that the VPS/CentOS is closing my wss when RAM usage reaches 850+MB because the max allowed RAM is 1GB for my plan.
I do plan on increasing the plan to higher RAM when launching for production, but I have a problem that my shell script is not printing to log file what it is supposed to.
Here is my wss_service.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
check=true
while [ "$check" = true ]
do
    startS=$(date +%s)
    dates=$(date '+%d-%m-%Y_%H-%M-%S')
    name="WSS_ServerJar_"
    new="$name$dates"
    files="./Log/$new.log"
    touch $files
    echo $files >> $files 2>&1
    echo "*** WSS Server started ***" >> $files 2>&1
    java -jar WSS_Server.jar >> $files 2>&1
    sleep 5
    echo "*** JAR Crashed ***" >> $files 2>&1
    endS=$(date +%s)
    diff=$(($endS-$startS))
    echo "diff=$diff; startS=$startS; endS=$endS;" >> $files 2>&1
    pass=120
    if (( pass > diff ));
    then
        check=false
        echo "Failed in short time: $diff" >> $files
    fi

done
```

Here is what is printed in the log file when the system closes my WSS due to RAM usage limit:

```
./Log/WSS_ServerJar_28-07-2023_01-35-13.log
*** WSS Server started ***
2023-07-28 01:35:14.874 [main] INFO  Application - Autoreload is disabled because the development mode is off.
Inside Application
2023-07-28 01:35:15.982 [main] INFO  Application - Application started in 1.162 seconds.
2023-07-28 01:35:16.655 [main] WARN  i.netty.util.internal.MacAddressUtil - Failed to find a usable hardware address from the network interfaces; using random bytes: a5:f2:64:ba:ab:26:51:3f
2023-07-28 01:35:16.823 [DefaultDispatcher-worker-2] INFO  Application - Responding at https://0.0.0.0:1234
2023-07-28 03:46:32.491 [KtorShutdownHook] TRACE io.ktor.server.websocket.WebSockets - Shutdown WebSockets due to application stop
2023-07-28 03:46:32.494 [main] TRACE io.ktor.server.websocket.WebSockets - Shutdown WebSockets due to application stop
```

Here is what is printed if I manually crash the shell script by ctrl+C or even from htop kill the process:

```
./Log/WSS_ServerJar_28-07-2023_13-48-13.log
*** WSS Server started ***
2023-07-28 13:48:14.628 [main] INFO  Application - Autoreload is disabled because the development mode is off.
Inside Application
2023-07-28 13:48:15.515 [main] INFO  Application - Application started in 0.971 seconds.
2023-07-28 13:48:16.101 [main] WARN  i.netty.util.internal.MacAddressUtil - Failed to find a usable hardware address from the network interfaces; using random bytes: c8:9d:92:76:47:73:29:09
2023-07-28 13:48:16.291 [DefaultDispatcher-worker-2] INFO  Application - Responding at https://0.0.0.0:1234
2023-07-28 13:48:27.859 [KtorShutdownHook] TRACE io.ktor.server.websocket.WebSockets - Shutdown WebSockets due to application stop
2023-07-28 13:48:27.860 [main] TRACE io.ktor.server.websocket.WebSockets - Shutdown WebSockets due to application stop
*** JAR Crashed ***
diff=21; startS=1690532293; endS=1690532314;
Failed in short time: 21
```

**I am not able to understand why the *** JAR Crashed *** is not printed when the system is stopping my .sh or .jar?**

Comment: I m guessing that since the java process is consuming too much resources, when it is terminated, the parent process is also terminated as well, that being the bash script, so it wont continue to execute the rest of the script

Comment: though this is OS implementation dependent, so take with a pinch of salt

Comment: So how do I get what I want to print? And how do I restart the JAR if its been crashed by the system?

Comment: Have you considered replacing your bash script with a system service ? I do not know what CentOS uses, but on SystemD based distributions, you should be able to create a "unit file" to start and restart automaticallly your java process, all managed by the system (including log saving).

Comment: amanin, how to do this? I do not know what this system service is and how to integrate logging?

Comment: If you're on CentOS 7 or newer, you should be able to use systemd for this. In summary: create a "unit file" describing your service (how to launch it, when to restart it, etc.). Then, put it in systemd configuration directory and reload systemd. But for more in-depth guides, you wll have to search articles [like this one](https://www.opentechguides.com/how-to/article/centos/169/systemd-custom-service.html)